# How to track object inside heap in node.js to find memory leak?

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks

I have memory leak, and I know where is it (I think so), but I don't know why it is happening.
Memory leak occurs while load-testing following endpoint (using `restify.js` server):

```
server.get('/test',function(req,res,next){
    fetchSomeDataFromDB().done(function(err,rows){
        res.json({ items: rows })
        next()
    })
})
```

I am pretty sure that `res` object is not disposed (by garbage collector). On every request memory used by app is growing. I have done some additional test:

```
var data = {}
for(var i = 0; i < 500; ++i) {
    data['key'+i] = 'abcdefghijklmnoprstuwxyz1234567890_'+i
}
server.get('/test',function(req,res,next){
    fetchSomeDataFromDB().done(function(err,rows){
        res._someVar = _.extend({},data)
        res.json({ items: rows })
        next()
    })
})
```

So on each request I am assigning big object to `res` object as its attribute. I observed that with this additional attribute memory grows much faster. Memory grows like 100Mb per 1000 requests done during 60 sec. After next same test memory grows 100mb again, and so on. Now when I know that res object is not "released" how I can track what is still keeping reference to res? Let say I will perform heap snapshot - how I can find what is referecing res?

---

screenshot of heap comparison between 10 requests:

[image]

Actually it seems that `Instance.DAO` is leaking?? this class belongs to ORM that I am using to query DB... What do you think?

One more screen of same coparison sorted by #delta:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems more likely that the GC hasn't collected the object yet since you are not leaking `res` anywhere in this code. Try running your script with the `--expose-gc` node argument and then set up an interval that periodically calls `gc();`. This will force the GC to run instead of being lazy.

If after that you find that *are* leaking memory for sure, you could use tools like the [heapdump](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-heapdump) module to use the Chrome developer heap inspector to see what objects are taking up space.

Comment: I tried `gc()` already. If I call gc after each request, still memory increases, but slower because requests take much more time. Also tried to call `gc` after memory reaches 200MB - does not work, memory is still leaking. I also use lot of middleware which may have bug. I am trying to solve this since last week without a luck. I also inspected heapdumps in chrome, but it does not tell me anything (`arrays` are increased?)

Comment: If you've already tried all of that, then I would say your memory leak is elsewhere, not with the block of code you've shown in the question.

Comment: Yes I suspect that for some reason `res` is referenced from some root and is not garbage collected. But I can't figure out what is referencing res... I can't put code here because it is quite big app now...

Comment: I updated my question with screenshot of heapdump comparison - what do you think about it?